# Can't declare top in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using following code to quickly assign `window.getComputedStyle` to a variable:

```js
const {
  width,
  height,
  left
} = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('canvas'));
console.log(width, left, height)
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But when I want to declare `top`, it returns:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier top has already been declared

```js
const {
  width,
  height,
  left,
  top
} = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('canvas'));
console.log(width, left, height)
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But I haven't declared it before and it seems that it does work with left.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) is a [global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) in the browser. That means it's already defined in the context you're trying to define it in. You can name it something else:

```js
const {
  width,
  height,
  left,
  top: topStyle, // this basically renames "top" to "topStyle"
} = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('canvas'));

console.log(width, left, height, topStyle)
```

Or assign the computed style to a variable and access it there:

```js
const canvasStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('canvas'));

console.log(
  canvasStyles.width,
  canvasStyles.left,
  canvasStyles.height,
  canvasStyles.top
);
```

Or just don't try to define the variable in the [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_scope). Instead define it in a function:

```js
function accessPosition() {
  const {
    width,
    height,
    left,
    top
  } = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('canvas'));

  console.log(width, left, height, top);
}

accessPosition();
```

Comment: Thanks , the first approach is useful:)

Answer (score 1):

if you open your browser's developer tools and type:

```
console.log(top)
```

You will see it's already declared to represent the top-most window.